# Excel VBA interaction with Webpage

Tags: excel, vba, object

Good afternoon world!

I am trying to write some VBA code to gain access to a website, initially I am trying to write to the HTML elements in an IE website from stored information within a function.  Excel continues to tell me that I have a runtime error 91, and that the object variable or with block variable not set.  I am just past beginner in my VBA knowledge, so wonder if anyone can help. The website is not important, it is the process of getting into it.  I hope that someone can help.

```
Function LogInToSite(UID As String, PWD As String) As String
    
    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, ieDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim UserIDFld As MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement, PasswordFld As MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement, SigninBt As MSHTML.IHTMLInputElement
    Dim urlstr As String
    urlstr = "https://gmail.com/#login" 'Not the actual site
    
    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate urlstr
    
    
    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
       
        Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:02 AM#     
        Set UserIDFld = ieDoc.all.Item("email")    
        UserIDFld.Value = UID
        Set PasswordFld = ieDoc.all.Item("Password") 
        PasswordFld = PWD
        Set SigninBt = ieDoc.all.Item("Login")      
        SigninBt.Click                              
        
        Do Until objIE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        
    Set objIE = Nothing
    
    Exit Function
      
 End Function
```

Comment: Search Stack Overflow for 63294113 and you'll find some very good help there for your question

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Does the error go away if you execute code line by line using F8? Also, in the absence of the real url the actual relevant html is required (it is required anyway normally). There is no need for Exit Function and you should use a proper page load wait. Not just based on readystate.

Comment: The error comes at the useridfld.value